# Precision loss when transforming coordinates systems in GDAL (vector layers)

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system

Anybody knows the order of magnitude of the error introduced when transforming coordinates using GDAL?

More specifically, I would like to know if significant error is introduced when the transformation involves a change in Datum like, say, from NAD83 to WGS84.

Comment: If you have reference data about known ground control points or reference method that you know to be accurate you can test it yourself by converting coordinates with gdaltransform http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html.

Comment: @user30184 I don't have control points, in fact I was talking more of a change in data introduced when performing a transformation. Anyway, yous suggestion has got me on the right path, all I have to do is sample some points of the original data and measure against them as if they where 'control points'.